# The default entity from enum

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have property in Enum:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "payment_status", columnDefinition = "varchar(32) default 'ENTERED'", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PaymentStatus paymentStatus;
```

I want to get the default value for a field from enum

I have error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

The field cannot be null

**The error is when I want to create an object and save in the database without entering this field (PaymentStatus)**

EDIT:

```
@Basic
@ColumnDefault(value = "ENTERED")
@Column(name = "payment_status", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.ENTERED;
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: `private PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.ENTERED;`

Comment: @Andreas I know this solution but I have to use annotations. I have it imposed

Comment: Why do you have to use annotations? That seems like an arbitrary constraint. --- By using initializer, the field will immediately have the default value, so if you create a new object (using `new`), and your code calls `getPaymentStatus()`, the code will get the default value, not a `null` value, which is exactly what you'd want.

Comment: @Andreas I added EDIT in question. Could you say something about it?

Comment: `@ColumnDefault(value = "ENTERED")` is the same as `columnDefinition = "... default 'ENTERED'"`, i.e. it applies to the DDL, and therefore only to the database.

Answer (score 2):

`default 'ENTERED'` tells the database to use value `'ENTERED'` if the column is not included in the `INSERT` statement. Since the column is in the class, JPA will always include it in the `INSERT` statement.

To make JPA fill in the default value, simply assign it with an initializer, so it has that value until replaced by you (calling setter method), or replaced from database (when reading from there).

```
private PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.ENTERED;
```

Comment: Should I leave what I have and add `private PaymentStatus paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.ENTERED;` ?

Comment: @DevNet Yes, why not? If a record is insert by other means than this JPA code, you want that same default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a default in the database and if you want to leave it to the database to set the default value then you need to prevent a null being inserted to that column in the SQL insert statement

You would then need to look at what your JPA provider offers in that area. In Hibernate, for example, you would simply annotate your Entity with `@DynamicInsert`:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicInsert.html

> For inserting, should this entity use dynamic sql generation where
>   **only non-null columns get referenced** in the prepared sql statement?

It should be noted that defining a default in the JPA annotations (as you have done) only has any effect on DDL generation i.e. if you are having your JPA provider generate or update your schema and has to effect on any insert or update operations.